# Is there a dictionary for Transliterated Arabic?

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, arabic

Is there a dictionary for the meanings of transliterated Quarnic Arabic, e.g.
*"lahu maa fis samaawate wa maa fil arze"*?

If I was to put in a single word e.g. *"lahu"*, it should give me the meaning.

Comment: "lahu" is construct you will never find in an Arabic dictionary!

Answer (score 6):

If it is about translating words from transliterated arabic, [this "fuzzy arabic dictionary"](http://fuzzyarabic.herokuapp.com/) is quite good. It is also able to tell you that "lahu" is probably "لَهُ" and means something like "to or for him", but does not allow you to translate whole sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some extensive research on this question, but I haven't found any resources but one: [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com). Although it's never completely accurate, Google Translate should serve as a basic interpreting tool for Transliterated Arabic.

To use it, follow these steps:

1. Click on the link above.
2. Translate from Arabic to English.
3. Make sure the first option, *marhaban --> مرحبا*, is checked in the dialog box in the bottom left corner.
4. Translate your transliterated Arabic.

[image: Check]

Answer (score 0):

This is a proper Dictionary with in depth search engine as opposite to simple word look-up 
https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/